# Why does softwareupdate stall in terminal after successful download?

Tags: macos, terminal, software-update

I am using the command `softwareupdate -i -a` to download and install macOS updates for macOS Sonoma. After successful download the command does not return:

```
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Downloading macOS Sonoma 14.1.1
Downloading: 100.00%
Downloaded: macOS Sonoma 14.1.1
█
```

How can I proceed to update my system via the terminal?

I am trying to automate updating the whole system, this is my first stop - updating the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restart and then observe if the update processed. If not, try

```
softwareupdate -i -a --restart --agree-to-license
```

You can dump the internal state at any time with `softwareupdate --dump-state` and look in /var/log/install.log file any time the console app doesn't show enough detail if you stream the logs and search for **softwareupdated**.

Comment: just restarting the system did not trigger the update, I ran the suggested command with the options to restart and agree to license and the mac restarted and installed the updates. thanks. Also something to note the option --restart can only be used with root privileges.

Comment: Agreed @Human - I hate to tell people sudo since they need to know what that means and be comfortable doing their research. copypasta can be a terrible thing. Also, I've never had `--agree-to-license` be necessary, but it's there and why not script it in case you get stuck. Best of luck and feel free to answer / edit mine if you find it needs a tweak going forward.